Exclude items on a pivot table filter
I want to exclude items on a pivot table filter.
I get an error with the filter. For this one I get

error 1004 "Unable to get the Pivotfields property of the pivottable class

I would also like to add a function that first selects all items in the filter then excludes multiple items.
Sub ExcludeItemsFromFilter()
    
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pf As PivotField
    Dim pi As PivotItem
    
    'Set the pivot table object
    Set pt = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    
    'Set the pivot field object
    Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Headquarter")     '**ERROR ON THIS LINE**
    
    'Loop through all the pivot items in the pivot field object
    For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
        If pi.Name = "Applied Materials, Austin (58460)" Or pi.Name = "Applied Materials, Inc., Dallas (33741)" Then
            pi.Visible = False 'Exclude the item from the filter
        End If
    Next pi
    
End Sub

I also tried this and I get

error 438 "Object doesn't support this property or method".

Sub ExcludeItemsFromBICubeFilter()

    Dim objCube As Object
    Dim objFilter As Object
    Dim strFilterName As String
    Dim strItemName As String
    
    'Set the filter name and item names to exclude
    strFilterName = "Headquarter"
    strItemName = "Applied Materials, Austin (58460)"
    
    'Set the cube object
    Set objCube = ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
    
    'Set the filter object
    Set objFilter = objCube.Filters(strFilterName)   '**ERROR ON THIS LINE**
    
    'Exclude the specified item from the filter
    objFilter.Members(strItemName).Exclude = True

End Sub


Can you run this code and check if the names are correct? For Each pf In pt.PivotFields: Debug.Print pf.Name: Next

I get a "Compile error: Invalid outside procedure"

Possible to see your file?

Since you are setting pt to ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable3") make sure you are on the sheet with PivotTable3 when you run your macro, otherwise you will get error 1004.
I created a clean workbook with a very simple data table (below), inserted a Pivot Table (renamed to PivotTable3 to match your code), and ran your first code as-is (except for adding an apostrophe in your line with the error to separate the comment). Everything worked as expected - if the above tip doesn't work, can you try the same and see if it's a problem with your code or the workbook?
Data table:

Result:

Code:
Sub ExcludeItemsFromFilter()

Dim ws as Worksheet
Dim pt As PivotTable
Dim pf As PivotField
Dim pi As PivotItem

'Set worksheet object
Set ws = Sheets("your_sheet_with_pivotttable3") 'replace with your sheet name

'Set the pivot table object
Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3")

'Set the pivot field object
Set pf = pt.PivotFields("Headquarter")     ' **ERROR ON THIS LINE**

'Loop through all the pivot items in the pivot field object
For Each pi In pf.PivotItems
    If pi.Name = "Applied Materials, Austin (58460)" Or pi.Name = "Applied Materials, Inc., Dallas (33741)" Then
        pi.Visible = False 'Exclude the item from the filter
    End If
Next pi

End Sub


Thanks Rob, please see my answer with a screenshot of what my pivot table looks like

Are you sure you are running the macro while the sheet with the pivot table is active? To make your code a little more bulletproof, I'd do it this way, so that you're not dependent on being on the right sheet: Dim ws As Worksheet : Set ws = Sheets("sheet_with_pivottable"): Set pt = ws.PivotTables("PivotTable3")
